# Binomial coefficients with non positive integer coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am told to find the value for the following binomial coefficients:

$\binom{-1/3}{3}$  and  $\binom{-5}{3}$

but i cant find the answer. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

$\binom{x}{3}$ is defined as $\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{6}$.